Summing data from specific rows in power query
I made a mini query here to represent the issue I'm having. I'm trying to find a measure or function I can use in power query that will give me the sum of the sales amount but only for rows where "Product Use" says "Kitchen".
FYI I'm using Excel 2016
(https://i.sstatic.net/A2SZsH38.jpg)
I've been researching all day and cannot find anything even though this seems like a very simple thing.

This can be done in PQ in several ways depending on exactly what you need. Please edit your question to provide your data as text which can be copy/pasted, perhaps using this Markdown Tables Generator,  as well as an example (which could be a screeshot) of your expected results from that data. See also Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?

This is the sample data I used for test.

I think you need to do the calculation in powerpivot
Total: =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Table1[Sales Amount] ),
    FILTER ( Table1, [Product  Use] = "Kitchen" )
)



This worked great but I'm realizing that I need to be calculating the sum of the sales amount for both kitchen and entertainment together with the same function. I tried using 2 filters and using an AND in the filter function to filter for both Kitchen and entertainment but nothing seems to be working. I know you can have multiple criteria filters using "*" but everywhere I looked it seems to be only for filtering with criteria in multiple columns instead of the same column. Is there a way to do this so that "Total" shows 1200?

you can try this
Total: =
CALCULATE (
SUM ( Table1[Sales Amount] ),
FILTER ( Table1, [Product  Use] in { "Kitchen","Entertainment"} )
)
